# What is the most suitable way to work on an iOS project from two edges - graphical and programmatical?

Tags: ios, graphics

i'm currently working on a project by myself as the main developer(quite new to ios), my graphical abilities are limited and now i'm thinking of adding a graphical designer that would work with me.
i would like to know, what is the most common, accepted and suitable way to arrange my project so it would be the easiest way to integrate with the designer. 
should i ask for all the graphical files as jpeg? png? or maybe psd's? should the graphical designer have knowledge in iOS and xcode environment?
i also would like to know what is the right way to manage resources for different devices, since their resolution is different.
this is a theoretical question that i would like to learn from, thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your questions is a tad bit vague because there are lots of sides to designing an iOS App. Here are a few things to consider:

**1)**  Have you thought about how your app will work, what it will do and which bits of the design will be graphical rather than created via code? Don't go ahead with design, until you have thought about these things. We can't always use images for our iOS apps. Sometimes certain elements can and need to be created via code for reasons such as flexibility (work with multiple devices)/etc...

**2)**  Once you have decided how your app will work, talk to your graphical designer and share your idea. He/she will most likely come up with lots of suggestions for improvements, thus your design will change again.

**3)**  Once you are agreed on a design and price with your designer, ask for PNG and PSD files. I always find having a copy of the PSD file as well is incredibly useful, if you want to make a small change down the line, you won't have to pay your designer again for a simple change.

**Update**

In answer to your comment about not using `Auto Layout` and still having UI which will work with different iOS devices and screen sizes. Then consider the following methods:

**1)**  In Interface Builder (in Xcode), make use of the re-sizing tab to set the size and re-sizing properties of any and all UI elements.

[image]

**2)**  Sometimes you will find that certain elements in your UI (such as a UIButton), won't resize properly or wont be in the exact position you want on certain devices. To correct this, you can then use code to detect the iOS device and then make changes to the UI via code (such as moving objects up a few pixels/etc...).

Below is an example of how you can use code to detect what type of device (or screen size) is being used and then how you can update your UI accordingly:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {

    // Target device is an iPhone or iPod Touch.

    CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

    if (result.height == 480) {
        // 3.5 inch display - iPhone 4S and below

        CGRect frame = [button frame];
        frame.origin.x = frame.origin.x + 100; 
        frame.size.width = frame.size.width + 100;
        [button setFrame:frame];
    }

    else if (result.height == 568) {
        // 4 inch display - iPhone 5
    }

    else if (result.height == 667) {
        // 4.7 inch display - iPhone 6
    }

    else if (result.height == 736) {
        // 5.5 inch display - iPhone 6 Plus
    }
}

else if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

    // Target device is an iPad.
}
```

The above is simply an example and could work well when added to the `viewDidLoad` method.

**Update 2**

I would like to stress though, that while `Auto Layout` can be a pain to use and is annoying at times, it is worth it in the long run. It can save you from having to do a lot of extra work. The above methods I have stated do indeed work, but depending on your app, your UI, the devices and orientations you will be supporting, the above methods can end up creating extra unnecessary work which can be avoided by simply using `Auto Layout`.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thank you for your answer. so if understand correctly, if i already closed the issue of working through the storyboard only, plus the designer will always be available to do some cropping, you would go with getting the resources as png's? also, what to do with different screen sizes from this angle? thanks again

Comment: @Max Well in Xcode you have to use images such as PNG or JPEG files for the images that you want to add to your UI. You can't use PSDs in Xcode (to my understanding). However I would still ask for the PSD files, because you may want to make some edits to them in the future. This will save you money.

Comment: @Max In regards to the different screen sizes, use ```Auto Layout``` in the interface builder in Xcode. This will help with re-sizing your UI for the different iOS devices.

Comment: thanks! what if i choose not to work with auto layouts? how can i reach the same effect?

Comment: @Max No problem, I updated my answer in answer to not using Auto Layout :)

Comment: @Max I just made another update to the code I added in my answer. The new update will allow you to also detect if the end device is an iPhone/iPod Touch or if it is an iPad. This will be helpful for UI adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

Always ask for PSD, this will give you all layers you need for your graphics and you can extract the images without the designer. If he does have a knowledge of iOS programming he can do that for you.

Also my advice is to find someone who has a deep understaning of iOS user experience and has read all of the Apple guides.

Comment: +1 for "and has read all of the Apple guides". This is vital, its makes for a much better UI and your app is more likely to be featured if Apple like it.